# Reactjs: how to write a method to handle component creation and unmount

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So let's say there is acomponent which displays 2 child components: a *document list* and *the selected document*. By default *the selected document* component is not rendered, only when a document is selected from the list. And i also want this whole thing work when a new document is selected from the list.

There is a `state` which holds the document content and responsible for *the selected document* rendering, so i thought i'm going to set it to **null** in the method which handles the list item selection in order to unmount the previously created child component. Like this (excerpts from the parent class):

```
 handleResultListItemClick(docname) {
    if (this.state.sectioncontainer != null) this.setState({sectioncontainer: null},()=>{console.log("muhoo");});
    var selected_doc = this.state.resultlist.filter((doc) => {
      return docname === doc.properties.title;
    });
    this.setState({sectioncontainer: selected_doc[0].content.sections},()=>{console.log("boohoo");});
  }

...

render() {
  return (

    ...

    {this.state.sectioncontainer != null && <SectionContainer listOfSections={this.state.sectioncontainer}/>}
  );
}
```

The only problem is that state handling is not fast enough (or something) in react, because putting the `state` nullification and its new value setting in the same method results in no change in ReactDOM.
With the above code, the component will be created when the parent component first rendered, but after selecting a new doc in the list results in no change.

How should i implement this in way which works and also elegant?

I found this: [ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(container)](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html#unmountcomponentatnode) in the official react docs. Is this the only way? If yes, how could i get this `container` 'name'?

**Edit:**

Based on the answers and thinking the problem a bit more through, i have to explain more of the context.

As kingdaro explained, i understand why there is no need to unmount a child component on a basic level, but maybe my problem is bit more sophisticated. So why did i want to unmount the child?

The documents consist of several subsections, hence the document object which is passed to the child component is an array of objects. And the document is generated dynamically based on this array the following way (excerpt from the SectionContainer class which is responsible to display the document):

```
  buildSectionContainer() {
    return this.props.listOfSections.map((section, index) =>
      {
        if (section.type === 'editor') return (
          <QuillEditor
            key={index}
            id={section.id}
            modules={modules}
            defaultValue={section.content}
            placeholder={section.placeholder}
          />
        );
        else if (section.type === 'text') return (
         <div key={index}>{section.value}</div>
        );
      }
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.buildSectionContainer()}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

The SectionContainer gets the array of objects and generate the document from it according to the type of these sections. The problem is that these sections are not updated when a different doc is selected in the parent component. I see change only when a bigger length array is passed to the child component. Like the firstly selected doc had an array of 2 elements, and then the newly selected doc had 3 elements array of sections and this third section is added to the previously existing 2, but the first 2 sections remained as they were.
And that’s why i though it’s better to unmount the child component and create a new one.

Surely it can happen that i miss something fundamental here again. Maybe related to how react handles lists. I just dont know what.

**Edit2:**

Ok, figured out that there is a problem with how i use the QuillEditor component. I just dont know what. :) The document updates, only the content of QuillEditors doesnt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your current solution doesn't actually do anything is because React's state updates are batched, such that, when setState is called a bunch of times in one go, React "combines" the result of all of them. It's not as much of a problem with being "not fast enough" as it is React performing only the work that is necessary.

```
// this...
this.setState({ message: 'hello', secret: 123 })
this.setState({ message: 'world' })

// ...becomes this
this.setState({ message: 'world', secret: 123 })
```

This behavior doesn't really have much to do with the problem at hand, though. As long as your UI is a direct translation of state -> view, the UI should simply update in accordance to the state.

```
class Example extends React.Component {
  state = {
    documentList: [], // assuming this comes from the server
    document: null,
  }

  // consider making this function accept a document object instead,
  // then you could leave out the .find(...) call
  handleDocumentSelection = documentName => {
    const document = this.state.documentList.find(doc => doc.name === documentName)
    this.setState({ document })
  }

  render() {
    const { document } = this.state
    return (
      <div>
        <DocumentList
          documents={this.state.documentList}
          onDocumentSelection={this.handleDocumentSelection}
        />

        {/*
          consider having this component accept the entire document
          to make it a little cleaner
        */}
        {document && <DocumentViewer document={document.content.sections} />}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: This looks good - hopefully OP can see that unmounting the previous component should be unnecessary with this example.

Comment: I hope so as well, happy to provide additional clarification if needed Just wasn't sure exactly how much I needed to explain here.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt and kind feedback guys! You are right i forgot about how react merges setState requests. However… I already have the proposed solution to render the child component. I added more details to my question under **edit**, pls check it!

Comment: Ok, figured out that the problem is with how i use the QuillEditor component. Every other sections of the document update themselves, except the content of these components. Thanks for the thoughts anyway!